# Ada: Difference between interface and abstract tagged type?

Tags: interface, ada

According to Adaic, an interface in Ada is defined as
a "tagged type with no components and no concrete operations". It can be used for multiple inheritance.
In contrast, an abstract type is a tagged type intended for use as an ancestor of other types, but which is not allowed to have objects of its own.

Is the essential difference between both just the multiple inheritance feature of the interface? Can the types otherwise be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An interface cannot have any components, and all operations for one must be abstract. An abstract tagged type may have components and may have non-abstract operations.

A concrete type may extend multiple interfaces, but may only extend a single tagged type.

"IMHO, Interfaces are worthless."
Randy Brukardt, ARG member and ARM editor

Comment: There are also task, protected & synchronized interfaces. For a use, see for example [A18.28](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-18-28.html); I don’t know whether it was essential to use an Interface here (doubt it).

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I personally think interfaces may be useful for some OOP design patterns to define the required (pure virtual) procedures for types.

Comment: @digital_hog Interfaces are useful in other areas.  Even though Ada implements interfaces using type extension, there are other ways to implement interfaces.  Interfaces are extremely useful when doing Top-Down software design, which isn't restricted to OOP design choices. Being able to design your software around multiple abstract interfaces that interact is a powerful tool that can make both maintenance and reuse much more improved.  Think of Interfaces more like dynamic contracts.

Comment: There are uses for interfaces, but they are not that frequent.